# How does hostname resolution / lookup happen in Linux?

Tags: linux, rhel, configuration, hostname, nslookup

I am new to Linux and need to know how the nslookup command resolves hostnames.

What are the configuration files that are used by the nslookup command? I need to know the exhaustive list of files that are used by nslookup.

Also explain the execution flow of the nslookup command.

How are the files /etc/hosts and /etc/system/network tagged to nslookup?

Recently I found a blog post that said one of switch configuration files is used by nslookup - [nsswitch](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ch11s02s02.html) but even this one didn't work after adding entries in the /etc/hosts file.

I have searched the internet and didn't get any specific answer. I got only a vague answer. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Check with hosts manual `~$ man hosts`

Answer (score 2):

`nslookup dig host` only use DNS and their only direct file is `resolv.conf` -- but if you use a DNS *server* you run locally or otherwise control *that* can use other files to determine or supply data.

Normal name resolution (e.g. for programs) is different and does use `nsswitch.conf` and often other files including `/etc/hosts` -- see https://serverfault.com/questions/303716/linux-command-line-utility-to-resolve-host-names-using-etc-hosts-first